# In codeigniter how to get a reference to the child controller from a method in parent controller when that method is called from the child controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose I have two child controllers of MY_Controller,say Child_1 & Child_2.In MY_Controller I have two methods method_1 & method_2 as

```
abstract class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public abstract function method_1();//children will give custom implementation

   public function method_2()
   {
     some code ...
     /*Here I want to call method_1() of the child controller that have called this method i.e. method_2* automatically */
   }
}
```

I am calling **method_2()** from **child_1 & child_2** using

```
class Child_1 extends MY_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public function method_1(){//custom implementation goes here}

   public function some_method()
   {
     ...some code
     $this->method_2();//call inherited method method_2()
   }
}
```

A similar code for child_2

Comment: This code is correct you can use $this->method_2() call to call the parent's method. But why do you call a child's method in parent class, that's the opposite of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public abstract function method_1();//children will give custom implementation

    public function method_2()
    {
    // some code ...

    $this->method_1(); //Call the method directly it will implement the child's method
    /*Here I want to call method_1() of the child controller that have called this method i.e. method_2* automatically */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.Actually I am calling the child's method in parent class method because the parent class needs the child specific data to proceed forward & every child will have its own custom implementation of the method that generates this data.But the parent class method that calls this child specific method  can be common to all children.Please tell me is it really wrong to do this.

Comment: A parent class object should never be dependent of any of its child though what you are doing is theoretically possible. If you explain the requirement there could sure be some workaround to your problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the Example#1 in the following link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php . Aren't they doing the same thing I am trying to do(or you did in the code in your reply).Can the manual be wrong.Help me out here

Comment: Now I see it. That's absolutely fine. This is the advantage of using abstract class instead of interfaces that you can define a common method.

Comment: Well I also hope that that approach is correct as per OOP standards.And thanks for your prompt replies